# Cake php form helper. Substitute input values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp-1.3

Im use **cakephp 1.3**. I have form like this:

```
<form id="id" class="validationEngine" method="post" action="/some/path">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><? __('Select one'); ?></span>
        <?=$this->Form->input('Bla.bla1', array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => false,
            'div' => false,
            'options' => array(
                'option1' => 'value1',
                '0ption2' => 'value2',
                'option3' => 'value3'
            )
        ));?>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><? __('Select two'); ?></span>
        <?=$this->Form->input('Bla.bla2', array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'label' => false,
            'div' => false,
            'options' => array(
                'option1' => 'value1',
                '0ption2' => 'value2',
                'option3' => 'value3'
            )
        ));?>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><? __('text one'); ?></span>
        <?=$this->Form->input('Bla.bla3', array(
            'class' => 'form-control validate[required]',
            'label' => false,
            'div' => false,
            'type' => 'text'
        ));?>
    </div>
    <!-- 
    *
    *  There more inputs with 'type' => 'text' 
    *
    -->
</form>
```

So i have 2 selects and ~10 inputs.
I need to when you select, for example, '`value1`' in '`Select one`' and '`value3`' in '`Select two`' insert values in my inputs depending on selects values. This values (default texts) stored in array.
How can i do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem for javascript to solve, not Cake PHP.

You haven't described your problem very clearly though – I'm not sure what exactly you mean be "substitute values in my inputs".

Comment: And you haven't *answered* the question very well. This should be left as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Fair point. I couldn't decide which but I guess you're right.